# Adding page numbers when writing a PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to automate the process of building PDFs that contain pandas data frames.  However, I would like to add page numbers to the bottom right corner of my pages. I would also like to know if I can improve my existing code.

So far I have written a script that takes two pandas data frames, puts them in separate pdfs and then merges them together to create a final pdf.

```py
    from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
    from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
    from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
    from reportlab.platypus import *
    from reportlab.lib import colors
    from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
    import pandas as pd
    import io
    import numpy as np
    from reportlab.lib import colors
    from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, inch
    from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

    data = pd.read_csv('data1.csv').dropna()

    colwidths = 50

    GRID_STYLE = TableStyle(
                [('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
                ('ALIGN', (1, 0), (-1, -1), 'RIGHT')])


    t1 = Table(np.array(data).tolist());

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("report1.pdf", pagesize=letter)

    element = []

    t1.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN',(1,1),(-2,-2),'RIGHT'),
                           ('TEXTCOLOR',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.black),
                           ('VALIGN',(0,0),(0,-1),'TOP'),
                           ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(0,-1),colors.black),
                           #('ALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
                           #('VALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                           ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,-1),(-1,-1),colors.black),
                           ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                           ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                           ]))

    element.append(t1)
    doc.build(element)


    data2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
    t2 = Table(np.array(data2).tolist());

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("report2.pdf", pagesize=letter)

    element2 = []

    t2.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN',(1,1),(-2,-2),'RIGHT'),
                           ('TEXTCOLOR',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.black),
                           ('VALIGN',(0,0),(0,-1),'TOP'),
                           ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(0,-1),colors.black),
                           #('ALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
                           #('VALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                           ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,-1),(-1,-1),colors.black),
                           ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                           ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                           ]))


    element.append(t2)
    doc.build(element)

    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
    pdfs = ['report1.pdf', 'report2.pdf']
    merger = PdfFileMerger()

    for file in pdfs:
        merger.append(file)

    pdf = merger.write('result.pdf')

    for page in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
        pdf_page = pdf.getPage(page)
        pdf_page.mergepage(watermark_page)

    merger.addBookmark(pagenum)
    merger.close()
```

I don't have any error messages currently. I am hoping to have a table per page and a script that is capable of creating a PDFs with as many pages as tables I receive as this number could vary. All pages need to have a page number on the bottom right-hand corner of the page.

I have seen attempts to do this using watermarks but I don't understand it and I am not sure if it is a useful approach here.

Comment: Do you think this helps? - http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/08/12/reportlab-how-to-add-page-numbers/
Also coming to the improvements, I can see a lot of repeated code. For example, the styles in `TableStyle` is the same for both cases. And instead of generating two pdfs and merging them, would it be possible to combine the two data frames and then generate the final pdf at once? Say by reading `t1` and `t2` and then doing `element.append(t1)` then `element.append(t2)` and then `doc.build(element)`

Comment: Thanks very much for this - with regards to repeating the code. I was planning to get my head round how it all works and then I would create a for loop to build a page for every table I load. With this page numbering code, I get how the code works but I am not sure where it fits in my script - any pointers?

Comment: I've added an answer. Please check if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is completely inspired by this blog post - http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/08/12/reportlab-how-to-add-page-numbers/

I don't completely understand how these internal functions work, but the basic idea is to modify some of the internal functions of `canvas.Canvas` so that page number is automatically added to every page generated.

First, create a sub-class of `canvas.Canvas` class to modify the internal functions as follows,

```py
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.platypus import PageBreak, SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# Custom Canvas class for automatically adding page-numbers
class MyCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pages = []

    def showPage(self):
        self.pages.append(dict(self.__dict__))
        self._startPage()

    def draw_page_number(self, page_count):
        # Modify the content and styles according to the requirement
        page = "{curr_page} of {total_pages}".format(curr_page=self._pageNumber, total_pages=page_count)
        self.setFont("Helvetica", 10)
        self.drawRightString(195*mm, 272*mm, page)

    def save(self):
        # Modify the save() function to add page-number before saving every page
        page_count = len(self.pages)
        for page in self.pages:
            self.__dict__.update(page)
            self.draw_page_number(page_count)
            canvas.Canvas.showPage(self)

        canvas.Canvas.save(self)
```

Now generate the PDF. In your case,

```py
TABLE_STYLE = TableStyle([('ALIGN',(1,1),(-2,-2),'RIGHT'),
                          ('TEXTCOLOR',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.black),
                          ('VALIGN',(0,0),(0,-1),'TOP'),
                          ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(0,-1),colors.black),
                          ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,-1),(-1,-1),colors.black),
                          ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                          ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                        ])

content = list()

# This should be refactored into a for-loop
data_one = pd.read_csv('data1.csv').dropna()
t1 = Table(np.array(data_one).tolist())
t1.setStyle(TABLE_STYLE)
content.append(t1)
content.append(PageBreak())

data_two = pd.read_csv('data2.csv').dropna()
t2 = Table(np.array(data_two).tolist())
t2.setStyle(TABLE_STYLE)
content.append(t2)
content.append(PageBreak())

# Now generate the PDF at once with page numbers
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("result.pdf", pagesize=letter)
doc.build(content, canvasmaker=MyCanvas)
```

I've tested this by generating a dummy PDF and it worked well. Hope this helps.